# JPA separate search multiple words in one column

Tags: spring-boot, jpa

Is there any syntax for searching for multiple words in one column independently from the ordering when the word count is unknown?

Something like:

```
@Query("Select a from Article a where a.text LIKE in :words")
List<AbstractNewsContent> findNewsletter(List<String> words);
```